# Django extends not including child file

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view that returns a page from my template dir, successfully, no problem:

```
def home(request):
    c = {}
    return render_to_response('home.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If **home.html** is a simple webpage with no *extends*, it returns fine.

However, if I use an include, say {% extends "base.html" %}, it simply returns the base.html without adding in the content from the child home.html. What could be causing this?

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
This is the homepage.
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment, this is returning a copy of base.html like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Why is it not including the content or title block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *base.html* block named *content* is appearing twice. You may want to name first block as `title` e.g. `{% block title %}{% endblock %}`

Django recommends that you shouldn't define multiple template blocks with same name.

From [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

*Finally, note that you can't define multiple block tags with the same name in the same template. This limitation exists because a block tag works in "both" directions. That is, a block tag doesn't just provide a hole to fill -- it also defines the content that fills the hole in the parent. If there were two similarly-named block tags in a template, that template's parent wouldn't know which one of the blocks' content to use.*

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a gentleman and a scholar. I will accept your answer once the SO time restriction passes :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks for the kind words!